# Push file to repository from pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I have GitLab pipeline where I get files from the repository, update data in the file and want to push it back to the origin

Here is my pipeline file

```
    variables:
  NUGET_URL: ********
  GITLAB_BASE_URL: ******
  GITLAB_ENDPOINT: ********
  MAJOR_VERSION: ********

stages:
  - publish-nuget-package
   
step-publish-nuget-package:
  stage: publish-nuget-package
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
  before_script:
    - dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
    - export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
    - dotnet tool install -g AWS.CodeArtifact.NuGet.CredentialProvider
    - dotnet codeartifact-creds install
  script:
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt-get upgrade -y
    - apt-get dist-upgrade -y 
    - apt-get -y autoremove
    - apt-get clean
    - apt-get -y install git
    - git config --list
    - x=$(awk '{print $2}' ./package-version.txt)
    - ((x++))
    - echo "${x}"
    - echo "VERSION_NUMBER:\ ${x}" > ./package-version.txt
    # - latestTag=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)
    # - echo "$latestTag"
    # - ((latestTag++))
    # - git tag ${latestTag} --force
    - git remote set-url origin $GITLAB_BASE_URL$API_TOKEN$GITLAB_ENDPOINT
    - git remote -v
    - git push origin ./package-version.txt --force -o ci.skip
    # - git tag
    - cd Monspire.EmailSender.Contracts
    - dotnet pack -c Release /p:Version=$MAJOR_VERSION."${x}"
    - echo "VERSION_NUMBER:\ ${x}" > ./package-version.txt
    - cd Monspire.EmailSender.Contracts/bin/Release/
    - dotnet nuget push Monspire.EmailSender.Contracts.$MAJOR_VERSION."${x}".nupkg --source $NUGET_URL
  environment: development
  tags:
    - monspire
  only:
    - versioning
```

At this line `- git push origin package-version.txt --force -o ci.skip` I get this error

> $ git push origin ./package-version.txt --force -o ci.skip
> fatal: invalid refspec './package-version.txt'

How do I need to fix this?

Comment: You cannot push a *file*. Git never pushes a *file*. What Git deals with is *commits;* you can push a *commit*. So, make a commit.

Comment: How I can do this via pipeline?@torek

Comment: I don't know. That's why the above is a comment, not an answer. (You can probably just use the same everyday commands that you would use in everyday Git, provided that pipelines allow this.)

Comment: I guess it need to be git command so which one? @torek

Comment: That's a different question. See [ask].

Comment: It's not a different question, command is scope of this one! @torek

Comment: And what did your search of Git commands turn up? It seems clear you have not put any effort into this yet.

Answer (score 1):

What you do there is strange you are updating, upgrading, dist-upgrading autoremoving packages. This is a real war.
At least dist-upgrading I would never do automatically because a dist-upgrade can also add a new kernel and all this in "don't-ask-me-just-do-it" mode (-y) is more than funny. The funniest thing is that you also install git last where I then ask myself where your gitlab-runner is installed. But that's how it is, you never stop learning.

Of course you do not need to put such a command like "git remote set-url" in a pipeline that you execute automatically, there is no need to specify the origin each time, because your Git remembers the origin.

```
    - git init
    - git remote set-url --push <name> <url>
```

Normally you must init your repository before you add a origin.
This should *not* be part of a pipeline. The use of a pipeline is to deploy your changes, make tests or build a product
So you start editing your pipeline by first adding the changes you made to your local workspace repository

```
    - git add .
```

this adds all modified files, but if you want to add just one file ...

```
    - git add -A -- C:\Users\Eugene\Workspace\Project\package-version.txt
```

then you simply push (to) origin. You do not need to specify the file, that is the job of git add

```
    - git push
```

or if you have a complicated situation with different branch names

```
    - git push origin branch_here:branch_there
```

And to verify ask for the status

```
    - git status
```

or using -u to show you the untracked changes to be committed

That's all the magic